# Adding values of a key, based on the similarity of other key

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

So I have list of python dictionary which look like this:

```
[{"word": 'app idea', "post" : 'i just had an app idea', "likes" : 22},
{"word": 'app idea', "post" : 'this is a great app idea', "likes" : 29},
{"word": 'app development', "post" : 'let us start our app development', "likes" : 32},
{"word": 'app development', "post" : 'app development will take time', "likes" : 23},
{"word": 'app data', "post" : 'delete the app data', "likes" : 32}]
```

I want to add likes where word is same

so the final output looks like this

```
[{"word": 'app idea',  "likes" : 51},
{"word": 'app development',  "likes" : 55},
{"word": 'app data',  "likes" : 32}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in one line, using `itertools.groupby`, dictionary & list comprehension

- group the dicts by value of the `word` key
- rebuild the dicts using the sum of the `likes` values and the value of the `word` key, using dict comprehension in a list comprehension

code:

```
list_of_dicts = [{"word": 'app idea', "post" : 'i just had an app idea', "likes" : 22},
{"word": 'app idea', "post" : 'this is a great app idea', "likes" : 29},
{"word": 'app development', "post" : 'let us start our app development', "likes" : 32},
{"word": 'app development', "post" : 'app development will take time', "likes" : 23},
{"word": 'app data', "post" : 'delete the app data', "likes" : 32}]

import itertools

result = [{"word":k,"likes":sum(v["likes"] for v in vl)} for k,vl in itertools.groupby(list_of_dicts,key=lambda k : k["word"])]
```

result:

```
[{'word': 'app idea', 'likes': 51}, {'word': 'app development', 'likes': 55}, {'word': 'app data', 'likes': 32}]
```